# How can I get the values that are common to two dictionaries, even if the keys are different?

Tags: python, dictionary

Starting from two different dictionaries:

```py
dict_a = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 4, 'e': 6}
dict_b = {'d': 1, 'e': 6, 'a': 3, 'v': 7}
```

How can I get the common values even if they have different keys? Considering the above dictionaries, I would like to have this output:

```py
common = [1, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create sets from the values:

```
list(set(dict_a.values()) & set(dict_b.values()))
```

This creates an intersection of the unique values in either dictionary:

```
>>> dict_a = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 4, 'e': 6}
>>> dict_b = {'d': 1, 'e': 6, 'a': 3, 'v': 7}
>>> list(set(dict_a.values()) & set(dict_b.values()))
[1, 3, 6]
```

Unfortunately, we can't use [dictionary views](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) here (which can act like sets), because dictionary values are not required to be unique. Had you asked for just the keys, or the key-value pairs, the `set()` calls would not have been necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
commom = [item for item in dict_b.values() if item in dict_a.values()]
```

Comment: + 1 Thanks, your solution also works but I think it could be slower than the one proposed by @Martijn Pieters.

Answer (score 2):

The intersection expression `&` requires 2 sets but the method counterpart can work with any iterable, like dict.values. So here is another version of the Martijn Pieters solution :

```
list(set(dict_a.values()).intersection(dict_b.values()))
```

My 2 cents :)